# css form- issue with margin/padding-- code & image included

Tags: css, forms, padding, margin

I'm having issue with an html/css contact form. Ideally, I'd like the 'label' and 'input' to be level with eachother, with a 1px border-bottom extending from the label to a defined endpoint(not a defined width). Is this possible? What am I missing?

```
<div id="contact">
        <div id="invite">
            <h1>Let's Talk.</h1>
            <h2 class="postinfo">
                <p>Have you got a project needing an eye for detail and a creative touch? <br>I&#39;d love to hear from you. </p>
            </h2>
        </div><!-- end invite -->
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name"><h1>Name:</h1></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="" />

                <label for="email"><h1>Email:</h1></label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="" />

                <label for="subject"><h1>Subject:</h1></label>
                <input type="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" />

                <label for="message"><h1>Message:</h1></label>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder=""></textarea>

                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </fieldset><!-- end fieldset -->
        </form><!-- end form -->
    </div><!-- end contact -->

#contact {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 310px;
    width: 533px;
}
#invite .postinfo {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: ;
    width: 150px;
}
#form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -85px;
    margin-left: 230px; 
}
#form fieldset {
    border-style: none;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
#form fieldset label {
    padding-right: 50px;
}
#form fieldset input {
    width: 300px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wF8.png

Comment: er, did I miss the announcment? Last I checked there was no `<contact>` element in any version of HTML.

Comment: yeah = this is html not xml. your css assumes there are valid elements called "contact" and "invite" and there are not. Restructure your html with classified divs with css to match. Also - Hs are block elements, and need to be set to "display:inline" if you want labels and inputs to line up, in this case. Also - you have 4 H1s, while there should be exactly one on any given page.

Comment: code has been changed, problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your code a bit and this is what I came up with:

Here is your HTML:

```
<contact>
<form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="clear">
            <label for="name"><h1>Name:</h1></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
            <label for="email"><h1>Email:</h1></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
            <label for="subject"><h1>Subject:</h1></label>
            <input type="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
            <label for="message"><h1>Message:</h1></label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </fieldset><!-- end fieldset -->
    </form><!-- end form -->
</contact><!-- end contact -->
```

and here is your CSS:

```
body  { font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif ;
    font-size:14px ;
    font-weight:bold ;
}

h1  { font-size:16px ;
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0 ;
}

contact {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 310px;
    width: 533px;
}
contact invite .postinfo {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: ;
    width: 150px;
}

contact form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -85px;
    margin-left: 230px; 
}

contact form fieldset {
    border-style: none;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

contact form fieldset label { width:100px ;
    float:left }

contact form fieldset input { 
    width: 200px;
    float:right ;
}

.clear  { clear:both ;
    line-height:30px ;
}
```

You'll need to play with your label and input widths depending on the font size you use.

Best,

Cynthia